# Adding a Floatformat to Django Custom Tag

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am using Django 1.8.3 and Python 3.4.3

I've got a custom tag that takes the value of two objects, divides one into the other and renders the total.  I did it this way because the two objects being divided are the Sum of many fields so I needed to do the final calculation of the totals.

What I need help with is, once the two values are divided into each other, the float renders up to 15 digits after the decimal and I tried to use `|floatformat`, but it doesn't seem to work on a tag.  I've searched and searched for an answer, but I can't seem to find whats probably right in front of me :)

Everything works, I just want to format the final value to a 2 decimal point.  Below is my code.

simple_tag.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.simple_tag()
def average(num1, num2):
    return float(num1 / num2)
```

traffic.html (my template)

```
{% if traffic_list %}
<tr>
    <th>Monday</th>
    <td>{{ total_sales.Monday }}</td>
    <td>{{ total_campaigns.Monday }}</td>
    <td>{{ total_ifs_signups.Monday }}</td>
    <td>{{ total_traffic.Monday }}</td>
    <td>{% average total_traffic.Monday total_sales.Monday %}</td>
</tr>
...
```

Resulting value of the above tag

```
30.345407503234153
```

I would like it to render

```
30.36
```

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Why is 30.3454 rounded to 30.36?

Comment: that was me looking at the screen too long :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can round the float in the tag definition:

```
@register.simple_tag()
def average(num1, num2):
   return round(float(num1 / num2), 2)
```

Or you can use `floatformat` filter like this:

```
{% average total_traffic.Monday total_sales.Monday as result %}
 <td>{{result|floatformat:2}}</td>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Going with rounding inside the tag to keep the template clean.  Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

When doing the average, you have to:

```
@register.simple_tag()
def average(num1, num2):
    a = float(num1 / num2)
    # if you want you can round it too
    # a = round(float(num1/num2))
    return format(a, '.2f')
```

Comment: Thank you for helping; it is much appreciated.